# How do I rename my local SQL development server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm a dev who inherited a mostly functioning box doing most of what I need. Except for the machine name is still that of the old dev (we name it "{username}-dt" or "{username}-lt" for ease of id on the network) and I want to rename it from old-username to my-username.

Naturally this will affect SQL as well, so I thought I would ask for more experienced advice on what I need to do before I rename my machine. I know there are some "sp_" sprocs to be run, but when do I run them? Do I need to restart my box before or after, and do I need a certain level of privilege? Will it destroy any existing windows-based auth on the box (those accounts are all AD accounts anyways)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[How to: Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx)

1. Rename the computer.
2. Restart the computer - SQL Server will recognize the new name during startup, but the `sys.servers` table will still contain the old name (you can run `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` to confirm it).
3. Run the `sp_dropserver` and `sp_addserver` procedures to update this table.

   *According to BOL, the [former](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174310.aspx) requires the **ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER** permission and the [latter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174411.aspx) - membership in the **setupadmin** server role; however, brief `sp_helptext` and Google investigation suggests that actually they both require this **ALTER ...** permission.*
4. Restart SQL Server and use `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` to verify that the previous step has been successful.

---

Apart from technical considerations explained in the [How to: Rename a Computer ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174310.aspx) article (e.g. computers involved in replication cannot be renamed), the thing I would worry most about is **finding and changing all the connection strings**:

- the ones in `app.config` and `web.config` files,
- the ones hard-coded in some prototype applications,
- the ones hidden somewhere deep in configuration of SharePoint, Analysis Services and other systems,
- the ones embedded in Excel files or Access databases).

Answer (score 4):

While this sounds hard it's actually very easy.

1. Rename the machine and reboot.
2. Connect to SQL as a sysadmin
3. Execute: EXEC sp_dropserver 'xxx'; --where xxx is the old hostname
4. Execute: EXEC sp_addserver 'yyy', 'LOCAL'; --where yyy is the new hostname
5. Restart the SQL Server service
6. Connect to SQL and execute; SELECT @@SERVERNAME;

Step six should indicate the name you put in where yyy is in step 4.. Success!

If you use Veritas/Symantec clustering you'll get very used to doing this ;)

Answer (score 3):

Drachenstern, rename it as you want, you'll be able to create an alias on your local machine - SQL Server configuration tool - to point you wherever you want.
Or do more work (but the proper one), as the first answer tells you.